# Query on impact of design due to change in behaviour -- OOP paradigm

Tags: java, oop

I have a below abstract class Critter,

```
/* Critter.java */

/**
 * The abstract class Critter defines a base class for anything(which can be empty)
 * that can exist at a specific location in the ocean.
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
public  abstract class Critter  {

    /**
     * Below data member defines a location of a Critter in an Ocean
     */

    Point location;


    public Critter(int x, int y){
        location = new Point(x,y);
    }

    public Point getLocation(){
        return location;
    }

    /**
     * This method computes the new value of location(which can be EMPTY) property of Critter.
     * No operation is performed as this is a base class.
     */
    public abstract Critter update(Ocean currentTimeStepSea);


}
```

---

which currently 3 subclasses inherit namely Shark class, Fish class and Empty class

---

```
/* Empty.java */

/**
 * The Empty class defines itself as an entity as it has some meaning/significance
 * being empty in an Ocean. Check update() method for more meaning.
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
public class Empty extends Critter{ ...}
```

---

```
/* Shark.java */

/**
 * The Shark class defines behavior of a Shark in an Ocean.
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
public class Shark extends Critter{ }
```

---

```
/* Fish.java */

/**
 * The Fish class defines the behavior of a Fish in an Ocean
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
public class Fish extends Critter{ }
```

---

My question is:

If there is a chance of adding a new behaviour(method) in Critter class based on future coming subclasses of Ocean creatures, Do you consider above design as a flaw?

If yes, How would you suggest me to proceed?

Additional info:
Remaining classes that are part of this application(not relevant to current query) are Ocean class, Point class, SimText class, Utility class.

Complete code can be seen(if required) at query section in [link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43921/suggestions-needed-after-modification-of-simulation-of-an-ocean)

Comment: This hobby app was written for problem in [link](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/pj1/readme)

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it. I definitely would not create subclasses for every type of critter - it creates a lot of classes without clear intent. Instead, I'd create different strategies for different critters and pass _those_ around to the owning critter (a la composition). For example, I'd create a SharkBehavior and a constructor on critter that sets the behavior on the critter, then call that behavior's update and getLocation methods. That way you don't need nearly as many things extending and messing with critter.  Just my opinion though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Here i created subclasses for each Fish Shark and Empty for reason mentioned as 8 points in problem link mentioned above. May be, you can comment on, if it make sense to create 3 subclasses becasue of those 8 points

Comment: Abstractions are only as good as they simplify our code. The goal is to write concise readable code. I'd probably just have a 2d array for the grid and pass a function  (well, functional interface since Java) to the constructor of critter to convey update. Novices often make the mistake of using design patterns invented and intended for applications with millions of lines of code on their 1000 lines app. Resist that temptation - abstractions are not free and add their own problems. Write simple code and refactor (change it) when abstractions make things simple. Abstraction is not a goal :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Oh you mean functional paradigm is more close for the solution. I know python and higher order functions in python, so are you saying that, behaviour should be passed as an argument to a function?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum  you say, Abstraction is not a goal ): there is a complete course on abstraction cs61A from berkeley, Do you think this should be considered as a intermediate concept to write concise readable code?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I understand passing function to constructor or method, but in my application, I did not get the concept of: 'pass a function (well, functional interface since Java) to the constructor of critter to convey update'

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces define common *behaviour*, abstract classes provide common *implementations*. Hence, simply create a Locatable interface that your critters implement:

```
public interface Locatable {
    Point getLocation();
}
```

When you have new behaviours, just create new interfaces to represent them that your critters implement:

```
public class Fish implements Locatable, Prey {}

public class Shark implements Locatable, Predator {}

public interface Predator {
    void eat(Prey prey); 
}

public interface Prey {
    void hideFrom(Predator predator);
}
```

Comment: But if i implement such interface at Shark Fish level, which looks intuitive, But How do i handle my client code. becasue am using polymorphism their? in Ocean.java?      this is the main problem
 
 public Ocean timeStep() {
  
  Ocean nextTimeStepSea = new Ocean(width, height);
  
  for (int row = 0; row < this.height; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < this.width; col++) {
    Critter creature = this.cellContents(row, col);
    nextTimeStepSea.addCritter(creature.update(this));
   }
  }
  return nextTimeStepSea;
 }

Comment: Can somebody answer this?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just add the update(Ocean currentTimeStepSea) method to the Locatable interface, all Critters will then need to implement the method and so you can iterate over all Critters calling the method without needing to know what type of critter they are i.e polymorphism.

Comment: i think this what i did, i placed update() method in critter class and implemented in all subclasses

Comment: class AddBehavior : ICalculatorBehavior {
    public String getOperator () {
        return "+";
    }
    public double performOperation (double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}//dynamicCalculatorObject.AddBehavior(new AddBehavior());